# A menu that stays on top with absolute position

Tags: jquery, html, css

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var offset = $(".menu").offset();  

    $(window).scroll(function () {  
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();  

        if (offset.top < scrollTop) {
            $(".menu").css({
                position: "fixed"
            });  
        }
        else {
            $(".menu").css({
                position: "absolute"
            });  
        }
    });  
});
```

CSS

```
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

As you imagine my menu always stays on top when scrolling down. But there is a catch here. My menu is positioned absolutely because it is located inside a large relative container div. However if I wish for the menu to stay on top I have to change the positioning to fixed, which all works fine but menu now gets displaced outside of the large container div! Is there a way to position my menu to always stay on top but to retain its absolute value? I really want that menu in one place, this means top:0 and right container border also 0!

Nothing moves outside of the central container and top is always 0.

**Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/t6nue/2/**

Comment: can you post it in a fiddle?

Comment: can you share the html and the css of the other divs?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove comma:

```
if (offset.top < scrollTop) {
   $(".menu").css({
      position: "fixed"//, //here no need to use comma
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem of jumping menu button like so:

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var offset = $(".menu").offset();  

    $(window).scroll(function () {  
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();  

        if (offset.top < scrollTop) {
           $(".menu").css({
                top: scrollTop - "8"
            });  
        }
        else {
            $(".menu").css({
                top: "0px"
            });  
        }
    });  
});
```

Notice I declare top position with jQuery variable: `top: scrollTop - "8"`

Problem solved :)